# netplan apply fails with "Cannot find unique matching interface for eth0"

Tags: wifi, ubuntu

Using Ubuntu 21.10, if I try to set a static IP for my raspberry in `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`, I have an error when I run `netplan apply`, that reads:

```
Cannot find unique matching interface for eth0: {'driver': 'bcmgenet smsc95xx lan78xx'}
```

I'm a positive my config is correct. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming from the other config file in `/etc/netplan`, `10-rpi-ethernet-eth0.yaml`. This file is not compatible with the latest version of netplan. Specifically, the line reading        `driver: bcmgenet smsc95xx lan78xx` is generating the error. A bug report has been filed [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netplan.io/+bug/1918421) and a fix will land soon.

Until then, you can find out which driver you are using on your Raspberry using the `lsusb` command. For me, the output is:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) SMC9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

So the driver that matches in the line is `SMSC9514`. Therefore, I will remove the other two from the offending line, so that it reads:

```
       driver: smsc95xx
```

If you have a different driver listed that matches one of the other globs, keep that one.

Now `netplan apply` no longer gives the error.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. When I run lsusb I don' see the Microchip Technology output at all

Comment: While I have 9 Pi's to play with, I actually faced this issue on a ThinkPad laptop running Ubuntu 22.04 and I just defined the driver that was basically returned by `lshw -C network` and this did the trick